# media element js use as background video

Tags: mediaelement.js

im trying to use media element as the video background of my website. And I have found 2 issues.

1. On Chrome, Firefox, the video does not loop, even though I have set loop=true
2. On Ipad and Iphone, the navigation on top of the video is not accessible. I can still see the navigation but I can not click on them

see my site in development here: dev.neuproject.com

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, try setting `loop="loop"` on the video tag.